# Return Multiple Objects Using ASP.NET MVC'S JsonResult Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, controller, jsonresult

Is it possible to Multiple Objects Using ASP.NET MVC'S JsonResult Class.... Here is a controller method which returns json object of my records but i also want to pass the count value....

```
var materials = consRepository.FindAllMaterials().AsQueryable();
var count = materials.Count();
var results = new PagedList<MaterialsObj>(materials, currentPage-1, pageSize);
return Json(results);
```

How to return count along with the `results` from asp.net mvc controller....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about creating an anonymous type and JSON'ing that?

e.g.

```
var resultCount = results.Count;
var genericResult = new { Count = resultCount, Results = results };
return Json(genericResult);
```

You can then eval your json string in your script as before but just query the Count and Results properties on your eval result.

Comment: My assumption was you were calling the eval function yourself. If you've done a jQuery call specifying a json result type, it will already have done that.

Comment: @Oscar that is true for this case, but in cases where the data you want to obtain isn't a simple property, you would need to pass an object like Neil has demonstrated.

Comment: how to read `Count` and `Results` in the ajax `success` property?

Comment: @RehanKhan , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10604171/2218697) to read Count and Results in the ajax success. Hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to send multiple objects which are dynamically identified to send.  [See this](http://tryconcepts.blogspot.in/2012/01/return-multiple-object-using-json-in.html).

Comment: Please instead of [just linking to a blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) include at least a summary of the answer here. By doing that your answer does not become invalid should the blog ever go offline. It makes your answer nicely self-contained. You can still link to the blog for further details.

Answer (score 0):

In C# part:

Using new keywork

```
var genericResult = new { homeworkData = homework, attachmentData = homeworkAttachment };
var result = this.Json(genericResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
return result;
```

In jquery side :

```
function getHomewrokDetailResponse(dataSent, result) {
if (result && result.homeworkData) {
    homeworkId = result.homeworkData.homeworkId;

    ....
}
 if (result && result.attachmentData) {
    xy = result.attachmentData.xyz;

    ....
}
```