# Tempdata not showing in image src in view ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set the image URL in my controller and pass it to view page using tempdata after successfully uploaded the img to folder. However, the tempdata value is not appearing in the view even though it was shown in the Response payload.

Please do let me know what can I improve on! Thanks!

Controller

```
[HttpGet]  
        public ActionResult UploadFile()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }

        String fileName = "";
        [HttpPost]  
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
        {  
            try  
            {
                string _path = "";

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
                {

                    string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + "-" + file.FileName);
                    _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);

                    fileName = _FileName;

                    file.SaveAs(_path);
                }  
                
                TempData["Img"] = _path;
                TempData["Msg"] = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File Uploaded Successfully!!");

                return View();
            }  
            catch  
            {  
                TempData["Msg"] = "File upload failed!!";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File upload failed!!");
                return View();  
            }  
        }
```

View (cshtml)

```
<div>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="Upload" class="zone" />
        <div id="dropZ">
            <i class="fa fa-camera fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p class="add">Add Photo</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    @Html.Raw(@TempData["Msg"])

    if (TempData["Img"] != null)
    {
    <img src = "@TempData["Img"]" />
    }
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnFileUpload').fileupload({
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
            imageMaxWidth: 1200,
            imageMaxHeight: 1200,
            imageCrop: false,   
            dataSrc: "",
            success: function (e, data) {
                console.log("Done");
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error");
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Is that `TempData["Img"]` data contains null on debug? Consider using `ViewBag` or `ViewData` (or a viewmodel) instead (TempData holds values between 2 subsequent requests).

Comment: You not doing anything with the view you return (e.g updating the DOM)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i did check using if null but it seems like there is value pass through to view in tempdata but it's just not showing out in view. Tried both viewBag and ViewData but result is the same.

Comment: But why are you returning a view anyway. Just return a `JsonResult` containing that data and update the existing `src` attribute (in fact you will need to create the `<img>` element since it does not even exist initially)

Comment: You're passing the `src` attribute as AJAX request but actually you're returning entire `View` - use a `return Json` and put `append` on the `img` tag with value from data response.

Comment: `return Json(_path);` and `success: function (data) { $(body).append($('<img/>').attr('src', data)); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke now is showing the viewdata but only on reload page and my data value is success which is totally different from the controller. Im confused

Comment: What do you mean on page reload? - your making an ajax call

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh opps sorry i get it now! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Stephen Muecke method, i was able to solved the problem as i was not doing anything with the view you return.

```
return Json(_path);
```

and

```
success: function (data) { $(body).append($('<img/>').attr('src', data)); }
```

Answer (score 2):

The view uses AJAX call to controller action method as this:

```
$('#btnFileUpload').fileupload({
    url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
    // other options
    success: function (e, data) {
        console.log("Done");
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

But actually you're returning an entire view instead of JSON response in `HttpPost` method. To set both image path and returned message with AJAX call, you need to return `JsonResult` with both values like this:

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
{
    string path;
    string msg;
    try
    {
        // file processing logic

        path = _path;
        msg = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
    }
    catch  
    {  
        msg = "File upload failed!!";
        path = string.Empty;
    }

    var result = new { Path = path, Msg = msg }; // return both image path & upload message
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, in your AJAX call `success` response use `append` & `html` method to replace `TempData` usage:

```
$('#btnFileUpload').fileupload({
    url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
    // other options
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Path != '') {
            $(body).append($('<img />').attr('src', data.Path));
        }
        $('#msg').html(data.Msg); // put a div with id='msg' attribute first (see HTML code below)
        console.log("Done");
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="Upload" class="zone" />
     <div id="dropZ">
        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="add">Add Photo</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

Related issue:

[how to return multiple variables with jsonresult asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604014/how-to-return-multiple-variables-with-jsonresult-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

On the server side:

```
   [HttpPost]  
            public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
            {  
                try  
                {
                    string _path = "";

                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
                    {

                        string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + "-" + file.FileName);
                        _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);

                        fileName = _FileName;

                        file.SaveAs(_path);
                    }  


                    return Json(_path);
                }  
                catch  
                {  
                    return Json("");  
                }  
            }
```

On the client side:

```
        success: function (data) {
if(data==="") alert("Image hasn't been uploaded successfully!");
        else 
    { 
    $('your-div').find('img').attr('src', data);
    alert("Image has been uploaded successfully!");
    }
    }};
```

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not exist, so `.find('img')` wont work -  it would need to be created

Comment: @StephenMuecke so that `img` should be created before file uploading. Just with css attribute `display: none;`. Then just use `.css()` function to change the value to `block`

Answer (score 0):

I try your TempData["Img"] in my project. It working fine. You need to only inspect your `<img src="TempData["Img"]"/>` and find where you are doing mistake. Plz see the below picture for help.

[image: Controller Code]

[image: View Code]

[image: User Interface]

Comment: Clearly you did not test it with OP's code (making an ajax call)!