# How can I create and return object in return statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create and return an object in this return call:

```
var Zones = _ZoneService.GetZones();
var userZones = _ZoneService.GetUserZones(user);
return Ok(//Here I need to return both Zones and userZones);
```

How can I create new on the go object to return these two.
Thanks...

Comment: Does `return OK(new { Zones, userZones});` work?

Comment: What is `Ok`? A method? Your question is hard to answer unless you provide the signature of the containing method and what `Ok` is.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok is function from `asp.net core` controller base.

Comment: Thanks all. This **return OK(new { Zones, userZones});** worked for me. @HimBromBeere Ok is the response in case of WebApi in .net core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Multiple Objects Using ASP.NET MVC'S JsonResult Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765082/return-multiple-objects-using-asp-net-mvcs-jsonresult-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Multiple Objects Using ASP.NET MVC'S JsonResult Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765082/return-multiple-objects-using-asp-net-mvcs-jsonresult-class)

Comment: Related: [How can I return multiple values from a function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c/748073), [ASP.NET Returning Multiple Variables to View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791585/asp-net-returning-multiple-variables-to-view)

Comment: @ S.Akbari have done that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)? Something like this:

```
return Ok(new { Zones, userZones });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to go is to creat a list, add the object to your list, and return the list. This way is also easyer if you need to work with these object.

To create a list, first we need to code a propper class:

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Object MyObj { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can create and populate the list:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item{ Id=1, MyObj= Zones},
    new Item{ Id=2, MyObj= userZones}
}
```

Now you can return your list using: `return items`

Answer (score -2):

You could also use an`out` parameter, like:

```
public Zones GetZones(..., out Zones userZones)
{
    uzerZones = _ZoneService.GetUserZones(user);
    return _ZoneService.GetZones();
}
```